# Hide UITextField in textFieldDidEndEditing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I'm trying to hide my UITextField in my app. 
I first tried to do it with a UIButton..

Therefor I made this:

```
-(IBAction)hide:(id)sender {

_textField.hidden = !_textField.hidden;

}
```

This worked but now I'm trying to do it automatically after editing so I wrote this code:

```
 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

 textField.hidden = YES;

 }
```

In the .h I put this code:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Could anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Is it possible to hide it with an animation? 
I tried this which wasn't working:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^
{ code.. }
]
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Did you set up delegate for you `_textField`? Check it in your xib/viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I'm working with a storyboard.. I only made this for my .h: 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

What should I need in my viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITextField's *hidden* property is a BOOL and cannot be animated. Try using the *alpha* property of the text field. It accepts floating-point values, where 0.0 if fully transparent, and 1.0 is fully opaque.

So you could animate UITextField's alpha to hide it:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0 
                 animations:^{ 
      textField.alpha = 0.0;
 }];
```

As beryllium said, you should also check if your text field actually has its delegate set up so that the *-textFieldDidEndEditing:* method gets called.

I assume you have a view controller set up something like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@end
```

Then you should connect the UITextField's *delegate* outlet in your storyboard to the view controller like this:

[image]

or you can do it programmatically in the *-viewDidLoad* method of your view controller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
     self.textField.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should manipulate the alpha valeue of your textField to animate it
For example:

```
textField.alpha = 1;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    textField.alpha = 0;
}];
```

Comment: And how could I make this in code? Could I use the code which I wrote here above?